# Jquery popup show and hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, show

I have a button once clicked shows a popup with a dark bg. I used some code i found on here and edited but it doesnt seem to show the pop up and brings up an error saying {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Can any one help? 
here is my demo

http://jsfiddle.net/6bZRA/

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#login-link").click(function () {
        $("#login-container-popup").dialog();
        $(".login-popup-darkbg").show();
    });

    $(".login-popup-darkbg").click(function () {
        $("#login-container-popup").dialog('close');
        $(".login-popup-darkbg").fadeOut(1000);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.ui-button-icon-primary', function () {
        $("#login-container-popup").dialog('close');
        $(".login-popup-darkbg").fadeOut(1000);
    });

});
```

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: May be this could help you:

```
$("#login-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#login-container-popup").dialog();
        $(".login-popup-darkbg").show();
    });
```

Use `e` in click event as it will prevent the default action to be fired of link.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bZRA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` error is by jsfiddle because you are reloading the page by clicking the link.

Set the href to something like `#` or `javascript:void();` to prevent this.